# Focus on an Input field with an animated search box in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an  animated search box, when you click the link with class btn-search, it will show and slide in a search form.

I would like to focus on the input field when the search form show.

I have added #searchInput to the input tag and use ViewChild and ngAfterViewInit. But it does not work and show my an error.
Can anyone please help me with this?
Thank you so much.

Nav.component.html

```
<div class="btn-nav navbar-right">
    <a href="#" class="btn-sm btn-default btn-search" (click)="clickSearchForm()">
      Search
    </a>
</div>
<div class="nav-search clearfix" *ngIf="isSeachForm" [@slideInOut]>
    <form class="navtop navbar-form home-search" role="search">
        <div class="search-group">
            <div class="input-group clearfix" id="nav-search-input">
                <input #seachInput type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Nav.component.ts

```
isSeachForm: boolean = false;
@ViewChild('seachInput') searchElementRef: ElementRef;

clickSearchForm() {
    this.isSeachForm = true;
    this.searchElementRef.nativeElement.focus();
}
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.searchElementRef.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to an elementRef that's inside *ngIf causes this because the element doesn't exist at component initialization. Simplest fix should be:

```
<div class="nav-search clearfix" 
[style.display]="isSeachForm ? 'block' : 'none'" [@slideInOut]>
```

Edit: this will likely break your animation though, but i'm sure you can figure out another way to do the sliding.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. There is no error message now, but focus on input field still does not work.

Comment: Hmm.. next problem might be that the container is still display:none when you try to focus inside it which can't be done. Dirty fix: call focus after a quick setTimeout delay?